# Show if a function has a local maximum, then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be analytic on a connected open set $S$ where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)$ respectively. If $u^4+v^4$ has a local maximum at a point in $S$, show that $f$ is constant in $S$

My attempt so far. I want to prove via contradiction.

Let's suppose to the contrary that $f(z)$ is non-constant on $S$. Since $u^4+v^4$ has a local maximum at a point $z_0 \in S$, there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that $B_{\epsilon}(z_0)\subset S$ and $u^4(z)+v^4(z)\leq u^4(z_0)+v^4(z_0)$ for all $z\in S$.

Since $S$ is open and connected, and $f$ analytic on $S$, then by the open mapping theorem it's image $f(S)$ and thus $f(B_{\epsilon}(z_0))$ is open and connected.

I feel like I am close to a contradiction, but am not sure where to go from here. Any hints/help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\delta >0$ sufficiently small the point $(1+\delta )u(z_0) +i(1+\delta) v(z_0)$ belogs to $f(S)$  (because $f(S)$ is open) so it can be written as $u(z_1)+iv(z_1)$ for some $z_1 \in S$. At the point $z_1$ $u^{4}+v^{4}$ exceeds the maximum value.

Comment: I knew I was overthinking it. This makes perfect sense, at least I was close! Thanks!